# Smooth complex threefolds with the same Betti numbers as $\Bbb CP^3$ but different rational cohomology rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, projective-space

Let $X$ be the smooth complex projective variety of complex dimension $3$. I need the examples of $X$ which have the same Betti numbers as $\mathbb{C}\mbox{P}^{3}$ but different cohomology rings over the rational numbers. Moreover, is there any complete classification of $X?$

Comment: This is just a remark that any threefold with same Betti numbers as $\mathbb P^3$ necessarily has the same _rational_ cohomology ring with $\mathbb P^3$ simply because there is only one nondegenerate pairing $H^2\times H^4\to H^6$ over $\mathbb Q$. However, the pairing does not need to be unimodular (over $\mathbb Z$), for example, when $X$ is the quadric threefold,  $H^4$ is generated by a line $L$ while $H^2$ is generated by a quadric surface $Q$ (hyperplane section), and $L\cdot Q=2$. What OP actually want to ask is "different cohomology ring over $\mathbb Z$".

Comment: @AGlearner: For a quadric $L \cdot Q = 1$ (because $Q$ is a hyperplane section), but $Q^2 = 2L$.

Comment: @Sasha: I see, thanks for the correction. $H^2_{\mathbb Z}\times H^4_{\mathbb Z}\to \mathbb Z$ is always unimodular by Poincare duality. It should be $H^2_{\mathbb Z}\times H^2_{\mathbb Z}\to \mathbb Z$ by cupping with Lefschetz class not unimodular, because $Q^3=2L\cdot Q=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three examples besides $\mathbb{P}^3$:

- a smooth quadric $Q^3$;

  a smooth quintic del Pezzo threefold $V^3_5 = \mathrm{Gr}(2,5) \cap \mathbb{P}^6$;

  a smooth prime Fano threefold of genus 12 (and degree 22) $V^{3}_{22}$.

The first two are rigid (do not deform); the last deforms in a 6-dimensional family.

EDIT: See Wilson, "ON PROJECTIVE MANIFOLDS WITH THE SAME RATIONAL COHOMOLOGY AS $\mathbb{P}^4$" for the classification.

Comment: Dear @Sasha, thanks for your answer, but how to show $H^3(V^3_5)=0$? And is the classification a consequence of classification of Fano threefolds plus computation on $H^3$?

Comment: @AGlearner: You can construct a birational transformation to $\mathbb{P}^3$ and check how the cohomology changes in the process.